# Spring WebFlux Handler Interceptor Adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am migrating a Spring MVC library to Spring WebFlux. There is a feature that lets our clients annotate their controller methods to perform custom validation (and applying some business rules) on incoming headers before granting access to the API.

In Spring MVC we had that accomplished by using HandlerInterceptorAdapter. Since WebFlux doesn't have anything similar I was trying out the solution as suggested by Rossen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21797#issuecomment-453477016). However it doesn't work for this use case since the method handler info is only available in `onSuccess` operator and its too late to get the info for annotation processing.

I was trying out the other approach suggested there using `@ModelAttribute` method on a `@ControllerAdvice` but that only work if the annotation is applied to the Controller class in our case the annotation is applied on methods of controller class.

Here is a sample https://github.com/ranarula/handleInterceptor with the issue

Any pointers on how to go about implementing the annotation processing in WebFlux will help.

Comment: Use aspects and handle it ?

Comment: Thanks @PawełGłowacz, tried that as well but I am having hard time getting access to ServerRequest or ServerWebExchange object. There isn't any `RequestContextHolder` available here. I even tried adding the exchange to Context via a WebFilter (`chain.filter(exchange).subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put(ServerWebExchange.class,  exchange));`) but still unable to get them in the aspect.

Comment: what kind of authentication are we talking about? oauth? roles? you should use spring method security.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf We have some custom authentication and using Spring security is not an option just yet.

Comment: why do you need the ServerWebExchange? can you please update your question with what type of logic you want to be performed when a method is annotated.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf added info about the need to access incoming request headers for validation.

Comment: Hi Rahul,

Did you find a solution for this? I am in the same situation and can't seem to find any help. Thank you.